# Using exoplayer in viewpager unable to scroll to another page

Tags: scroll, android-viewpager, exoplayer

Using exoplayer in viewpager i am  not able to scroll to next page when scrolling from top of the video and if I scroll outside the exoplayerview part it get scrolled, but when using texturevideoview it is working fine but i want to use exoplayer in my project.Any Solution.
Thanks in Advance.